# Bringing modules into project as git submodules - .info file doesn't have version info

Tags: 7, version-control

I'm adding modules into my git-enabled Drupal project as git submodules. Things seem to work fine except that when I bring in a git submodule and use the version I want, by doing a 'git checkout 6.x-1.1' for example, the resulting .info file doesn't have the following information (with this example taken from zen):

```
; Information added by drupal.org packaging script on 2011-04-05
version = "6.x-2.1"
core = "6.x"
project = "zen"
datestamp = "1302017816"
```

Whatever is added by this drupal.org packaging script is apparently added when the archive is prepared for download on drupal.org, and isn't added when the commit is tagged with a certain version in git. Now will these modules even be considered valid by Drupal when I try to enable it? And if so, I'm sure this would screw up the update process because update won't know what versions of existing modules it's comparing against.

So how can I fix this? I must have missed something, because clearly there's no way every git user can be expected to manually add in this metadata for every module every time they update.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Git deploy](http://drupal.org/project/git_deploy) project.

It exposes the version information by looking at the git information. I am not 100% if it supports git submodules, but it's worth a try.